# cookie is always not set

Tags: javascript, cookies

I am using the following code to set cookie, however, when I use `document.cookie` in console, it doesn't print the key-value pair I passed via `setItem()`. Anybody know what is the matter?

```
var docCookies = {
  getItem: function (sKey) {
    return decodeURIComponent(document.cookie.replace(new RegExp("(?:(?:^|.*;)\\s*" + encodeURIComponent(sKey).replace(/[\-\.\+\*]/g, "\\$&") + "\\s*\\=\\s*([^;]*).*$)|^.*$"), "$1")) || null;
  },
  setItem: function (sProperties) {

    var cookieString = "";
    var sExpires = "";

    for (var sKey in sProperties){
        console.log("inside for");
        if (sProperties.hasOwnProperty(sKey)) {
            // alert("Key is " + k + ", value is" + target[k]);
            console.log("inside if");
            cookieString += encodeURIComponent(sKey) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(sProperties[sKey])+"; ";


            }
    }
    console.log("outside for");

    document.cookie = cookieString.substring(0,cookieString.length-2);
    return true;
  },
  hasItem: function (sKey) {
    return (new RegExp("(?:^|;\\s*)" + encodeURIComponent(sKey).replace(/[\-\.\+\*]/g, "\\$&") + "\\s*\\=")).test(document.cookie);
  }

};



var expireDate = (new Date((new Date()).getTime() + (60*24*60*60*1000))).toUTCString();
var sProperties = [];
sProperties['_country'] = _country ;
sProperties['_language'] = _language ;
sProperties['_pageName'] = _pageName ;
sProperties['_products'] = _products ;
sProperties['_events'] = _events ;
sProperties['_server'] = _server ;
sProperties['_href'] = _href ;
sProperties['expires'] = expireDate ;

docCookies.setItem(sProperties);
```

Answer (score 0):

the cookie you want to save should be an Object

```
var sProperties = {};
```

Comment: I read all the array values and put them in `cookieString ` if you look closely

Comment: yeah I know, I mean this `var sProperties = []; sProperties['_country'] = _country ;` is incorrect. sProperties will not get any values. did I miss something?